# Passing hex enum parameter from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, enums, interop

I have a function in C that accepts a hexadecimal parameter. I need to call this function from C#. My current approach does not seem right because my C function is returning me the wrong number.

Here is the declaration of my C function:

```
enum tags {
    TAG_A = -1,
    TAG_B  = 0x00, 
    TAG_C = 0xC1,  
    ...
};
int myfunction(enum tags t);
```

Here is my C# code:

```
enum tags {
    TAG_A = -1,
    TAG_B  = 0x00, 
    TAG_C = 0xC1, 
    ...
    }

[DllImport ("mylibraryname")]
    public static extern int myfunction(tags t);

myfunction(tags.TAG_B);
```

I am on Mac and I am using Mono and Xcode to do all of these work. The C function can be assumed correct because it's an open-source library I downloaded. I think it's something wrong with the hexadecimal numbers but I'm not sure.

## solution:

I've ticked one answer, though actually setting the C# enum to long solved my problem. So in C#, I have:

> enum tags : long {
>       TAG_A = -1,
>       TAG_B  = 0x00, 
>       TAG_C = 0xC1, 
>       ...
>       }

Comment: That you use hex representation for your constants is irrelevant. You're probably using the wrong calling convention, or a differently sized enum. The C# enum takes 4 bytes, no idea about the c enum.

Comment: Why don't you just pass an integer?  At the end of the day that is all `tags` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexadecimal is simply a different way of expressing a literal integer value.  It's irrelevant to your problem.  For instance `TAG_B  = 0x00` and `TAG_B  = 0` both mean exactly the same thing.

The problem is possibly that the C `enum` is a 16 bit integer, whereas the C# `enum` is 32 bit.  Instead of creating an enum in C#, try just doing it as straight `Int32` values:

```
static class tags 
{
    public static short TAG_A = -1;
    public static short TAG_B  = 0x00;
    public static short TAG_C = 0xC1;
    // ...
}

[DllImport ("mylibraryname")]
public static extern int myfunction(short t);

myfunction(tags.TAG_B);
```

Or, as L.B suggested, you can just set the type of the `enum` members:

```
enum tags:short 
{
    TAG_A = -1,
    TAG_B  = 0x00, 
    TAG_C = 0xC1,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Size of c#'s enum doesn't have to be 4 bytes (`enum tags:short  {TAG_A = -1}`)

Comment: @L.B Awesome!  Thanks!  This is why I love stack overflow so much.  I learn something new every day.

Comment: Great answer! But I observed something weird: actually (enum tags:long {TAG_A = -1}) worked for me. I checked that my C enum is 4 bytes. My default C# enum is also 4 bytes. When I decorate my C# enum with "long", which is 8 bytes, the return value of my C function is correct. Otherwise it's always wrong. I found it hard to explain this phenomenon. @L.B

Comment: @CherryQu Maybe it's unsigned in C?

Comment: Hmm... I've found webpages saying that the default type of both C and C# enum is int. see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t(v=vs.80).aspx) and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On my architecture sizeof(enum_t), where enum_t is a typedef of an enum returns 4 bytes, so if the C# enum is 4 bytes as well i can't see the problem.

Check the size of the enum with sizeof for your architecture, if they match the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I checked, both my C and C# enums are 4 bytes, but changing my C# enum to 8 bytes does solve the problem.